# How to install qBittorrent search plugins?

Tags: qbittorrent

https://github.com/qbittorrent/search-plugins/wiki/Unofficial-search-plugins

> You can find here unofficial search engine plugins for qBittorrent that are made available by its users.

Only plugins for private websites have a readme.

Where do I move the downloaded Python (`.py`) files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Where do I move the downloaded Python (.py) files?

You can put them in a directory of your choice. Then use the following instructions:

> **Install your plugin**
>
> To install your plugin in qBittorrent:
>
> - Go to search tab in main window, click on "Search engines..." button.
> - Then, a new window will pop up, containing the list of installed search engine plugins.
>
>   [image: qBittorrent search plugins]
> - Click on "Install a new one" at the bottom and select your *.py python script on your filesystem.
> - If everything goes well, qBittorrent should notify you that it was successfully installed and your plugin should appear in the list.

Source: [How to write a search plugin](https://github.com/qbittorrent/search-plugins/wiki/How-to-write-a-search-plugin#install-your-plugin)